# Export different files

Tags: netlogo

I need to write a code that export different worlds depending upon the value of a global variable.

```
File names      Variable(percent)

0.20 percent           0.20

0.25 percent           0.25
```

Are they any string comparison function available to do so? Also, how would I convert a variable to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure I understand, you have a global variable (`percent`) and you want to get a filename from that? In that case, you can just do:

```
(word "percent " percent ".csv")
```

Replace `.csv` with whatever file extension you want.